# Seaborn plot not displaying over axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
counts = pd.DataFrame({'Pair A': {8: 4, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0},
 'Pair B': {8: 4, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0},
 'Pair C': {8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1},
 'Pair D': {8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0}})
```

I am just creating a simple plot using part of the DataFrame using the following code:

```
plt.figure()
sns.set_palette("pastel")
temp = pd.DataFrame(counts).drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], axis='index')
temp.index = temp.index + 1

temp.plot()
sns.set_style('ticks')
plt.ylabel('title')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.title('title')
plt.xticks(range(len(temp.index)), temp.index, rotation=45)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

But it results in an image that looks like this:

[image]

How can I center the plotting over the x-axis?

Comment: `name counts is not defined`, there seems to be something missing

Comment: @Yuca it is the name of the DataFrame, you can name it anything you want.

Comment: agree, but that would yield an error on your drop([0,1,2...)]

Comment: your only issue is `plt.xticks(range(len(temp.index)), temp.index, rotation=45)` if you remove that the plot behaves nicely

Comment: @Yuca true, but I want to label the plot as shown in the image, which doesn't happen for me without that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#xticks), and provide 2 positional arguments, the first argument becomes `locs` which are the x values where the labels will appear, the second becomes `labels` which are the tick label values.  Therefore with `plt.xticks(range(len(temp.index)), temp.index, rotation=45)` you are plotting x tick labels at position 0,1,2,3...., while your data are in a different range (8,9,10....).

Therefore if you want to customize your labels, you could change the `label` part, such as `plt.xticks(temp.index, ['x%s'% v for v in temp.index], rotation=45)`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this:

```
plt.xticks(range(len(temp.index)), temp.index, rotation=45)
```

causes the problem, and if replaced with this:

```
plt.xticks(temp.index, temp.index, rotation=45)
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: Was just about to answer to that effect. In fact, that is a redundant, unneeded line!

Comment: @Parfait it does seem a bit unnecessary, but is there a better way to specify all of the xtick labels? Because this is the only way I can seem plot without some of the labels being omitted.

Comment: That is the default setup of plotting. Maybe your actual data differs from posted, simplified version? I restarted with an empty Python environment and commented `plt.xticks` lines with no issue to x-axis.